# sysctl IPv6 funtional defaults

Tags: sysctl

ip-sysctl.txt:

```
accept_ra_defrtr - BOOLEAN
      Learn default router in Router Advertisement.

      Functional default: enabled if accept_ra is enabled.
                          disabled if accept_ra is disabled.
```

Does it mean accept_ra_defrtr is enabled if accept_ra is enabled?
Doesn't look like it:

```
$ echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/accept_ra
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/accept_ra_defrtr
0
```

Or is the new value just used internally and cannot be read (like writing to ipv6/conf/all/**)?

What does functional default mean?